# UITextView is not showing long text

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have an UITextView inside a UIScrollView. The textView display correctly when text is not too long.

[image]

But when text is long long, it is not showing text in textView. However, the textView is still selectable.

[image]

Here is my layout.

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: is scrolling disabled?

Comment: Yes. I disabled textView scrolling because it is inside UIScrollView

Comment: What type of emulator are you using is it possible that the Xcode emulator simply can't handle a "long long" piece of text.

Comment: Could you fix this?

Comment: As @Dennish says, it just emulator bug and works fine on real devices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem displaying very long text (33745 chars) in a UITextView and after experimenting with different copy lengths the limitation is with the simulator. If the number of chars was over 7435 the simulator did not show the text but I could scroll, copy etc.

But testing on several devices, the 33745 chars text displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just say

```
yourTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

and see the magic

Comment: textView inside UIScrollView, so it is wrong if enabled scrolling textView

Comment: does this meant you are resizing textview based on text you have?

Comment: as you said you have disabled scrolling, can you enable and see if it works? I will tell you solution then.

Comment: Yes. I disabled scrolling on textView. If i enabled, textView is not displaying because it is inside UIScrollView (which is enabled scrolling)

Comment: my final answer will be first set the text in the textview and then do the disabling of scrollview...

Comment: Hi, i've uploaded my code. Thank you so much! https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0zlfxyexn3rf3l/DemoTextView.zip?dl=0